# wpf datagrid FrozenColumnCount and usercontrol with adorner

Tags: wpf, datagrid, adorner

i have a DataGrid with FrozenColumnCount set to one and some DataTemplateColumns which contains a control which uses an adorner (simply lets say a TextBox with an Adorner which shows the Text "Unit" or somelike). If I use the HorizontalScrollbar the adorner lays before the fixed column. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the nature of [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx), they will always be on "top".

> Anything placed in the adorner layer is rendered on top of the rest of
>   any styles you have set. In other words, adorners are always visually
>   on top and cannot be overridden using z-order.

Comment: So in other words: it is impossible to achieve the behaviour i wanted with the adorner?